# Implementing array with min-value ints

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I currently have a nxn array of ints. I plan to initialize all the cells within the array with infinity and later change it if a value being compared to the cell is lower than the value inside the cell. Here is the pseudo-code of what I came up with so far, using -1 to represent infinity. What do you think? Is this the most efficient way, any bugs?

```
if(table[i][j] == -1 || (table[i][j] != -1 && table[i][j] > value)
    then table[i][j] = value
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would instead start with [`Integer.MAX_VALUE`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#MAX_VALUE). This way, the code could be simpler :

```
if(table[i][j] > value) {
     table[i][j]=value;
}
```

Notice that, were your array to contain doubles, you could even go as far as using [`Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#POSITIVE_INFINITY).

Comment: Thank you. More specifically I am implementing the Floyd-Warshall algorithm. So if table[i][j] > table[i][k] + table[k][j] then table[i][j] = table[i][k] + table[k][j]. If ik and kj were both MAX_VALUEs, would this upset the program in any way since they are being added?

Comment: Well, as its name suggest, Integer.Max_VALUE is the maximum possible value in the Integer world. Were you to add even `1`to it, you'll go out of Integer bounds and have as result Integer.MIN_VALUE-1 (yep, Integers are in fact circular).

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure that the value `-1` can be treated as a "reserved" value, you should be fine with such approach.

You could also consider encapsulating the datatype in some `PossiblyInfinitInteger` which has a boolean of whether or not it is set to infinity. Perhaps an overkill, I don't know.

Answer (score 1):

1. `if(table [i][j] == -1 || table[i][j] > value) then ...` does the same. I'm not sure, but the compiler may take care of this.
2. If `-1` is reserved, and the values cannot be less than `0`, your approach is correct, just compare `table[i][j] < value` and not visa versa.
3. If using `-1` as a reserved value is a problem, use Integer.MAX_VALUE:
   `if(table[i][j] == Integer.MAX_VALUE) then table[i][j] = value;`